# Mount a new state in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter. I have made a stateful widget that has multiple options for states, and I have no clue how to switch between them, or if it's even possible. Basically I have:

```dart
class SWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
    return _State1();
  }
}

class _State1 extends State<SWidget> {
...
}

class _State2 extends State<SWidget> {
...
}
```

I want `SWidget` to switch from `_State1` to `_State2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I don't understand your question but state is often tied to UI. If you need new state then chances are you're wanting to display something different. In that case, you'd want to distinguish the two states (and their UI components) by placing them in their own stateful widgets. You can then switch between the two widgets in a stateful or stateless widget:

```dart
class SWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  SWidget(this.condition);

  final bool condition;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return condition ? Foo() : Bar();
  }
}

class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FooState createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  var _foo = 'foo';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(_foo);
  }
}

class Bar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BarState createState() => _BarState();
}

class _BarState extends State<Bar> {
  var _bar = 'bar';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(_bar);
  }
}
```

I don't think I've ever seen anyone actually switch the state object out from underneath a widget. You can though easily change a widget's state by calling setState and toggling between values that way too:

```dart
class SWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SWidgetState createState() => _SWidgetState();
}

class _SWidgetState extends State<SWidget> {
  var _value = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Switch(
      value: _value,
      onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _value = value),
    );
  }
}
```